How to mark the current user location on Mapbox with Jetpack Compose latest version
I am trying to use Mapbox with Jetpack compose. I was able to add a pin at the clicked position. While trying to show the current user location on launching the app, I can't figure out the option. Can anyone help with this. I will give my current code below.

@Composable
fun MapUserLocation(){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        MapBoxMap(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
    }
}


@Composable
fun MapBoxMap(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val locationMarker = remember {
        context.getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_icon)?.toBitmap()
    }
    val mapView = remember {
        MapView(context)
    }
    val pointAnnotationManager = remember {
        mutableStateOf<PointAnnotationManager?>(null)
    }

    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            mapView.apply {
                mapboxMap.loadStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {
                    mapboxMap.style?.let {
                        pointAnnotationManager.value = annotations.createPointAnnotationManager()

                        if (locationMarker != null) {
                            mapboxMap.style?.addImage("marker-image-id", locationMarker)
                        }

                        location.apply {
//                            val locationComponentOptions = LocationComponentOp
//                            updateSettings {
//                                createLocationComponentPlugin()
//                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )

}

